# Where might the fault be in this battery checker circuit from an old camera?

Tags: circuit-analysis, repair

I'm repairing an old rangefinder camera, a [Canonet QL17 GIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonet_G-III_QL17).

I have had to do a lot of internal rewiring. All is now working, except for the battery checker functionality. I've included that part of the circuit diagram below.

When the switch closes, the bulb X61-7132 should light up (if the battery is still in good shape), but doesn't.

The battery is a 1.4V SR44 battery, instead of the mercury cell that the camera was originally designed for. I am pretty sure this shouldn't affect the operation of the checker circuit.

If I connect the lamp directly across the 1.4V circuit, it lights up, so I know that works.

[image: Canonet QL17 battery checker circuit]

When the switch is open, everything in the circuit floats up to 1.4V (actually, 1.53V according to the meter).

I have numbered some junctions in red in the diagram. When the switch is closed, I read (relative to ground):

- 1.53V at junction **1**
- 1.15V at junction **2**
- 0.40V at junction **3**

I am not sure if this seems correct, or what else to check.

However, it seems odd to me to read 1.53V at 1. I would expect at least a small voltage drop there, but it seems to be floating up. What should that transistor (2SC 182R, according to the parts list) be doing?

What should (and how) should I check next?

Comment: The transistor and/or its connections are damaged. There's no way \$V_{be}\$ should be greater than about 0.7V.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some way this could be reworded to fit the requirements? I tried to make it about understanding how such a circuit should behave, rather than being about repairing this particular camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the same voltage on the battery and the collector of the transistor (junction 1,) I'd say the transistor isn't conducting.

You say junction 2 has 1.15 V.  It ought to be closer to 0.7 when you close the switch.  The base of an NPN transistor should stay about 0.7V above the emitter when conducting.

That says to me that either the transistor is dead, or the emitter connection (the one with the arrow coming out of the transistor) is open (broken wire.)

So, in order of difficulty:

1. Check for continuity between the emitter leg of the transistor and switch.
2. Use a transistor tester to see if the transistor is OK.

---

If you don't have a transistor tester, use a multimeter.

1. Use diode test on the multimeter.  Positive lead on the base, you should read about 0.7 V when you connect the negative lead to each of the other pins.   Negative to base and positive lead to the other pins should read the same as an open circuit.
2. Use the ohms function if your meter  doesn't have diode test.  Positive lead to the base, negative to the other pins should show a (relatively) low resistance.  Negative to the base positive to the other pins should read as an open circuit.

You will have to remove the transistor from the circuit to test it.

---

The battery may have more influence on the circuit than you think.

This (primitive) circuit works by comparing the voltage of the battery under load with the 0.7 V base voltage.   A larger battery can supply more current for longer than a smaller battery.  The internal resistance of the battery also plays a part.  This circuit is intended to work with the specified battery type.

It is entirely possible that a modern battery with more capacity and lower internal resistance could push enough current through the transistor to kill it.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the transistor is indeed damaged. It's possible that the damage occurred while using the continuity tester on my meter, or perhaps it's heat-damage as a result of soldering.